# creation of thumbnail in php using ffmpeg is not working

Tags: php, ffmpeg-php

This is my php code to generate thumbnail of a video frame.

```
    extension_loaded('ffmpeg') or die('Error in loading ffmpeg');
    $vid = realpath('./Wildlife.wmv');
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    $moviefile  = $vid;
    $mov  = new ffmpeg_movie($moviefile,false);
    $img  = $mov->getFrame(10);
    $showImg  = $img->toGDImage();
    $mkNewImg  = new ffmpeg_frame($showImg);
    $maxWid  = 150;
    $oldWid  = $mkNewImg->getWidth();
    if($oldWid > $maxWid) {
    $newWid = $maxWid;
    }
    $newHgt  = $newWid / $movRatio;
    $mkNewImg->resize($newWid,$newHgt);
    $newImg  = $mkNewImg->toGDImage();
    imagejpeg($newImg,$mkThumbFile,40);
    imagedestroy($newImg);
```

When i execute this script i got error like

> Fatal error: Unable to locate ffmpeg_frame resource in this object. in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.php on line 14

Comment: `Line 14` actually is which line?

Comment: $oldWid  = $mkNewImg->getWidth();

Answer (score 0):

After `$showImg  = $img->toGDImage();` you need to use GD library functions to display the image.
GD also supports resize :)